# Python cannot cancel timer thread

Tags: python

I am trying to detect a long press event and cancel it if the button is released before the timer times out, however the timer never gets cancelled and fires if it is a short press or a long one:

```
from threading import Thread

but_down = Timer(1.5,long_press)

if(but=='down'):
    but_down.start()

else:
    but_down.cancel()

def long_press():
    print('long press')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code didn't run for me due to errors, but once I fixed those it worked fine:

This outputs **long press** after 1.5 seconds:

```
from threading import Timer
but = "down"
def long_press():
    print('long press')
but_down = Timer(1.5,long_press)
if(but=='down'):
    but_down.start()
else:
    but_down.cancel()
```

This outputs nothing:

```
from threading import Timer
but = "up"
def long_press():
    print('long press')
but_down = Timer(1.5,long_press)
if(but=='down'):
    but_down.start()
else:
    but_down.cancel()
```

I don't know what `but` is but my guess is that your `but=='down'` test might be the cause of the error.

Comment: Thanks, my code was pseudo code as if I included the actual it would not have made much sense. It turns out that it was related to scope in the end, thanks so much for helping.